# Update JTable with setValueAt

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to update the column's output of my JTable using the method setValueAt but it doesn't work, where is the error? This is my class.

```
public class TabellaQuery extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel {

    private ArrayList<String> colonne = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tabella = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    /**
     * Crea una tabella per visualizzare un ResultSet
     * @param rs: ResultSet da visualizzare
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public TabellaQuery(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

        for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
            colonne.add(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i));
        }
        while (rs.next()){
            ArrayList<String> riga = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                riga.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            tabella.add(riga);
        }
    }


    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {

    }


    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int arg0) {
        return String.class;
    }


    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colonne.size();
    }


    public String getColumnName(int arg0) {
        return colonne.get(arg0);
    }


    public int getRowCount() {
        return tabella.size();
    }


    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return tabella.get(arg0).get(arg1);
    }


    public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }


    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        tabella.get(arg1).set(arg1, (String)arg0);


    }

}
```

I call the method here but want the "edit" when there is a double click in a cell :

```
JButton firList = new JButton("x");


    JPanel leftPnl = new JPanel();


    JTable tabPOI=      new JTable();
    TabellaQuery modPOI= null;

    JScrollPane leftPnl=    new JScrollPane(tabPOI);

    public Creation(){


        super("Creation List");

        Container c = this.getContentPane();

        tabPOI.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);    
        tabPOI.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowListener());




        appPnl.add(firList);

        firList.addActionListener(this);



        totalPnl.add(leftPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        c.add(totalPnl);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize((int)dim.getWidth()+1, (int)dim.getHeight()+1);
        //setSize(400,250);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        setLocation((int)(dim.getWidth()-this.getWidth())/2, (int)(dim.getHeight()-this.getHeight())/2);
        setVisible(true);


    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String s = e.getActionCommand();
            if(s.equals("x")){

                tabPOI.setValueAt("aa", 0, 0);

            }

    private void createTablePOI(String m){

            try {

                modPOI = PersonDAO.load(m);

            } catch (MyException e) {
                System.out.println("error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            tabPOI.setModel(modPOI);
        }
```

Comment: You need to fire events to tell the JTable using the model that the data have changed. Extend AbstractTableModel, and call the appropriate fireXxx method. Your empty implementation of addTableModelListener also breaks the contract of the interface. Extending AbstractTableModel will also take care of that.

Comment: I have extended my class and in actionPerformed I called modPOI.fireTableCellUpdated(0,0) (where modPOI is my model) after tabPOI.setValueAt("aa", 0, 0) but nothing

Comment: That should be encapsulated in the table model. You don't want each and every caller to setValueAt() to rememer that it needs to fire an event. Make setValueAt() fire it. If you want us to be able to find the problem, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Remove the addTableModelListener method. It's already implemented in AbstractTableModel. And you replace that correct implementation by an implementation doing nothing. So obviously, tge listeners don't get registered, and are never called when an event is being fired. Aso remove the removeTableModelListener, of course. I already told you that in the first comment, BTW.

Comment: Sorry but I have not corrected the removeTableModelListener in this post but in my code it was ok. Now it works! I have removed the addTableModelListener and added modPOI.fireTableCellUpdated(0,0) after tabPOI.setValueAt("aa", 0, 0). Thank you!

Comment: Again, the call to fireTableCellUpdated should be done **inside** setValueAt(), for the reasons explained above.

Comment: yes, now I have done it :)

Comment: And if I want edit each cell of a column with different values?

Comment: setValueAt takes a row and a column as arguments. So what's the problem? Anyway, if you have a real new question, then delete this one and ask another real, clear question.

Comment: I think that there is an error when wrote the setValueAt method, because when edit a value of any cell, always changes the value of the same cell. For this reason I'm writing in the same post